# how to read json string from firefox response using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, firebug

Hi I have a scenario to read the json response from firefox(firebug) using selenium. Can anyone please help me in automating this. Is there a way to read the firebug logs from selenium. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to divide this test case into 2 parts? 1st part: test web GUI with Selenium, verify displayed content. 2nd part: run JMeter, perform the same operation using some sampler and verify returned json?

Comment: Thank you for this Marcin.. I tried this http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but it is the solution I found for our situation.

```
json.loads(res.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text)
```

Where res is the firefox webdriver.